# Is there any way to send an email to everyone in a Google Circle from Gmail? Or create a Contact Group from Circle?

Tags: gmail, google-plus

It looks like the answer is [no (at least from within Gmail)](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/1FYD7us-IK4).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Google Contacts Preview

1. Go to http://contacts.google.com/preview.
2. Click on Circles.
3. Click on the circle you want to send the email.
4. Click on the envelope icon on the top of the circle members list.
5. A compose email window will show up with all the circle members in the TO field.